# Spring WebFlux - Unable to return HTTP response in HandlerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to recreate `HttpServletResponse#getWriter` functionality in Spring WebFlux without success.

In Spring MVC, I would extend `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`, use mentioned `getWriter` for writing target response and return false from `preHandle` method. I'm trying to use the following code to recreate the same functionality. See following excerpts to see what I've tried so far without success.

```
@Component
public class CustomInterceptor extends RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
    @Override
    public Mono<HandlerResult> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Object handler) {
        exchange.getResponse().writeWith(s -> Mono.just(new SomeDto()));
        // creates Internal Server Error, custom WebExceptionHandler not called
        return Mono.error(new RuntimeException());
        // creates Internal Server Error, custom WebExceptionHandler not called
        throw new RuntimeException();
        // ignores response write
        return super.handle(exchange, handler);
    }
}
```

I've also tried to use a `WebFilter`, there is a possibility to change the response, however it's not possible to access `HandlerMethod` object, which is needed for further processing.

Any idea how to do this using Spring WebFlux? All ideas are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to handle the request/response in the new reactive `WebFilter`, eg.

```
@Component
public class SecurityWebFilter implements WebFilter{
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        if(!exchange.getRequest().getQueryParams().containsKey("user")){
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

Check my complete [webfilter sample](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/web-filter).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this is only a workaround that I've used as well, but it doesn't allow to access `HandlerMethod` which is required for reusing code that was possible to be done in `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`.